# mongodb count the number of consecutive matching docs and merge them into one

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider that I have a mongodb collection called `chatMessages` with these properties (using mongoose on nodejs):

```js
const schema = {
  _id: ObjectID,
  chatID: String,
  type: String,
  message: String,
  senderID: String,
  date: Date
}
```

Imagine that I have 5 documents in the collection:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 'id1',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'txt',
    message: 'first message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-02T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id2',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'groupedMsgs',
    message: 'second message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-03T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id3',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'groupedMsgs',
    message: 'third message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-04T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id4',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'txt',
    message: 'fourth message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-05T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id5',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'groupedMsgs',
    message: 'fifth message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-06T01:01:11.001Z')
  }
]
```

I want to query these documents such that consecutive rows (when ranked by date) with type of `groupedMsgs` are represented as one, as well as the number of consecutive rows that are present for each unique `groupedMsgs` in the final output. Concretely, I would like output as shown below:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 'id1',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'txt',
    message: 'first message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-02T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id2',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'groupedMsgs',
    message: 'second message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-03T01:01:11.001Z'),
    numConsecutiveItems: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 'id4',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'txt',
    message: 'fourth message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-05T01:01:11.001Z')
  },
  {
    _id: 'id5',
    chatID: 'alternateChat',
    type: 'groupedMsgs',
    message: 'fifth message',
    senderID: 'first_sender_id',
    date: new Date('0001-01-06T01:01:11.001Z'),
    numConsecutiveItems: 1
  }
]
```

Notice that the `third message` is not in the final output because it has type of `groupedMsgs` and consecutively follows another message with type `groupedMsgs`, and the `second message` has `numConsecutiveItems` of `2` for the same reason. More so, the `fifth message` is present because it doesn't immediately follow another `groupedMsgs` message, and its value of `numConsecutiveItems` is `1` for the same reason. What is an aggregation pipeline that can do this for me? My preference would be to avoid using `$accumulator`, `$function`, `$where`, and `$accumulator` to avoid running javascript during the query as that can slow down the query operation, but I'm open to all answers nevertheless.

Comment: Every document "_id" value needs to be unique across the entire collection.  You show more than one document with the same "_id".

Comment: You’re right, that was a copy paste mistake. I’ve edited the values to make them all unique.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but it is not recommended.

The method I used here (avoiding using "accumulator" per your request) is **not** a good practice and should not be used for large datasets, since it first groups all your data to one document and then multiply it by the number of documents. If you do choose to use something like that, I strongly recommend adding a $match phase before it in order to reduce the number of calculated documents.

In your case, you can run it for short periods of time (chunks), noticing that a message with "type" different from "groupedMsgs" is a good place to cut between them.

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$sort": { date: 1}},
  {"$group": {"_id": 0, 
        data: {"$push": {type: "$type", chatID: "$chatID", message: "$message",
          senderID: "$senderID", date: "$date", id: "$_id"}},
        docs: {"$push": {type: "$type", id: "$_id"}}}},
  {"$unwind": {path: "$data", includeArrayIndex: "data.inx"}},
  {"$addFields": {"nextType": {$cond: [
                                {$lt: [{$add: ["$data.inx", 1]},{$size: "$docs"}]},
                                {"$arrayElemAt": ["$docs",{$add: ["$data.inx", 1]}]},
                                "NA"]},
                "prevType": {$cond: [
                                {$gte: [{$add: ["$data.inx", -1]}, 0]},
                                {"$arrayElemAt": ["$docs", {$add: ["$data.inx", -1]}]},
                                "NA"]}}},
  {"$project": {data: 1, nextType: "$all.nextType.type", prevType: "$all.prevType.type",
      isfirstGroup: {$cond: [{$and: [{$ne: ["$data.type", "$prevType.type"]}, 
                                     {$eq: ["$data.type", "groupedMsgs"]}]}, true, false]},
      isLastGroup: {$cond: [{$and: [{$ne: ["$data.type", "$nextType.type"]},
                                    {$eq: ["$data.type", "groupedMsgs"]}]}, true, false]}}},
  {"$group": {_id: 0, starts: {$push: {isfirstGroup: "$isfirstGroup", origInx: "$data.inx"}},
                        ends: {$push: {isLastGroup: "$isLastGroup", origInx: "$data.inx",
                        data: "$data"}}}},
  {$facet: {
      groupedMsgs: [
        {$project: {startItems: {$filter: {input: "$starts", as: "item",
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$item.isfirstGroup", true]}}},
                    endItems: {$filter: {input: "$ends", as: "item", 
                    cond: {$eq: ["$$item.isLastGroup", true]}}}}},
        {"$unwind": {path: "$endItems", includeArrayIndex: "endItems.inx"}},
        {"$project": {data: "$endItems.data",  maxInx: "$endItems.origInx", 
                        minObj: {"$arrayElemAt": ["$startItems", "$endItems.inx"]}}},
        {"$addFields": {"data.numConsecutiveItems": {"$subtract": [{$add: ["$maxInx", 1]}, 
                                                                    "$minObj.origInx"]}}},
        {"$replaceRoot": {newRoot: "$data"}}
      ],
      others: [
        {"$project": {items: {$filter: {input: "$ends", as: "item", 
                                        cond: {$ne: ["$$item.data.type", "groupedMsgs"]}}}}},
        {"$unwind": "$items"},
        {"$replaceRoot": {newRoot: "$items.data"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  {"$project": {results: {$setUnion: ["$groupedMsgs", "$others"]}}},
  {"$unwind": "$results"},
  {"$project": {type: "$results.type", chatID: "$results.chatID", message: "$results.message",
                senderID: "$results.senderID", date: "$results.date", id: "$results._id",
                numConsecutiveItems: "$results.numConsecutiveItems"}},
  {"$sort": {date: 1}},
])
```

You can check it on the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1C5apUd4e5p .
Please notice I added one document to the playground to make things more clear

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There were some other constraints in my system that effectively required me to identify the aggregated messages as they get added to the database. So this task boiled down to `$filter`ing and `$project`ing the necessary fields to get my desired output. I'll try to find time to post exactly what worked for me, but you can read more [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-count-the-number-of-consecutive-matching-docs-and-merge-them-into-one/148372)